# wifi wont connect after trying to stop random disconnect

Tags: wireless, disconnect

After playing with the terminal and trying to fix my WiFi which was disconnecting at random multiple times in use now it won’t connect at all. Continues to prompt me for the WiFi access key which is entered correctly and doesn’t even attempt to connect. Please help!!!

Comment: Can you be more specific than "playing with the terminal"? what change(s) did you make? what wireless device (make + model) do you have?

Comment: So after some dabbling i found that my version was no longer supported, I went ahead and upgraded to ubuntu 18.04 now i have the ability to connect to wifi but now I'm unable to leave the area of the modem without losing connection to the network. any tips there?